# Can't upgrade to Modules: no "Migrate Settings" in console page

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to follow the directions on this page to convert my application from frontend/backend to module structure.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/converting

Specifically: it says the following:

> ### Manual migration
>
> If you’ve changed any of the frontend performance settings, you can’t upload module files  until you’ve migrated manually. A section titled **Performance Settings Migration** for  Modules appears in the Admin Console below the **Performance** section. This section displays code snippets that define an automatic-scaling module with performance settings equivalent to the current frontend. You can copy this code and use it to redefine your original frontend source file as a module. Press **Migrate Settings** to perform the migration. The app continues to run and you can now upload modules.

However, I do not see either the `Performance Settings Migration` section or the `Migrate Settings` button on the Application Settings page (or anywhere else in the dashboard).

Are they somewhere else?  Or is there another way to migrate?

(FWIW: I am using App Engine 1.9.2, and accessing the dashboard with Chrome.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change manually some performance setting, for example the quantity of idle instances and then click "save settings".

[image]

After that, the Performance Settings Migration for Modules will automatically appear

[image]